# Rounding depending on the multiplicity

Tags: javascript

The user enters 110 into the quantity, but since there are 20 pieces in the multiplicity, the quantity should automatically be recalculated upwards, it should be 120 pieces.

If, for example, the multiplicity is 100, and the client needs 1010 pieces, and he drives 1010 pieces into the quantity field, it should be recalculated to 1100 pieces.

**I need rounding up depending on the multiplicity of goods.**

```js
curValue = Math.floor(Math.ceil((curValue * this.precisionFactor )/this.precisionFactor))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way, I think, to achieve this, is to first see how many 'batches' of size multiplicity there are, rounding this up to the nearest integer, and then multiplying this by the multiplicity again. That is

```js
function multRound(amount, batchSize) {
  // round up to whole number of batches
  let numBatches = Math.ceil(amount/batchSize);
  
  // return the number times the size of each
  let total = numBatches * batchSize;
  return total;
}
```

Of course you can quite easily make this a one-liner, but I thought it'd be clearer to write it like this.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var curValue = 105;
var multiplicity = 20;

var amountToAdd = 0;
for (var i = curValue; i >= multiplicity; i = i - multiplicity ) {
    var temp = i - multiplicity;
  amountToAdd = multiplicity - temp;
}

console.log("new value: " + (curValue + amountToAdd))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the value by multiplicity, and get the integer part using `Math.floor()` and add `1` to it (since you want it to be rounded up). Then return this value multiplied by multiplicity.

```js
function round(currValue, multi){
  return multi*(Math.floor(currValue/multi) + 1);
}

console.log(round(105, 20));
console.log(round(1010, 100));
```